# Escaping the ampersand '&' in camlQueryOptions using SPServices when getting items from a folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, spservices

I've tried escaping the ampersand using `<![CDATA[]],` html encoded characters but it doesn't return any results.

My query looks like

```
CAMLQueryOptions : "<QueryOptions><Folder>DocLibrary & Example/AFolder</Folder></QueryOptions>"
```

To get items in the AFolder folder, It works with all other document libraries that don't have an ampersand and it works

How do I escape it?

Comment: Try the Query using CAML Query Builder and make sure the query returns data.

Answer (score 1):

I've got two solutions for you:

1. Replace the `&` with `&amp;`
2. Use CDATA: `<![CDATA[DocLibrary & Example/AFolder]]>`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Its not an Issue with the ampersand. But with a sharepoint list naming. I changed the name list so even though in spservices i can change the list name via

listName: New list Name

I have to use the original list name in caml queryoptions like

CAMLQueryOptions : "Original List Name/AFolder"